# Ping an ip address

Tags: android-networking

I am trying this code in order to ping that ip address in LAN.. the result return is Sorry.

thanks. if u help me

I want to ping that ip of a printer from my device. can i do this.

```
 String ip_address="\\10.28.81.9";
 boolean reachable=false;  
 TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
 InetAddress address;
try {
    address = InetAddress.getByName(ip_address);
    reachable =address.isReachable(3000); 
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}  
        if(reachable){
            txt.setText("Got it");
        }else{
            txt.setText("Sorry");

        }
```

Comment: i ahve also tired this by removing \\ with ip address but it still doent works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java code to ping an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the \'s at the begining of the address.

Comment: address = InetAddress.getByName(ip_address); is a problem as it is doing a forward lookup, and you are providing an address. You need to use getByAddress(String host, byte[] addr)